# Convert a pure imaginary number to polar form

Tags: complex-numbers

I know that when converting a complex number of the form $ z = a + bi $, you need to take the $\arctan$ of $\frac{b}{a}$. But what do you do if $a = 0$?

I know that the pure imaginary numbers live on the  $y$-axis of the Gauss Plane, so $ \theta = 90^\circ$ or $270^\circ $, but is there a way to know which one to use other than looking at the sign of $\Im(z) $?

Comment: $z = r\cos\theta + i r\sin \theta$ what $\theta$ for when the the real part is 0 and the other is not?

Comment: Why use anything but the sign?  Draw a picture of $z$ and you can't go wrong.

Comment: You generally have to be careful when using arctan due to the fact that in it's pure form it doesn't give you information about which quadrant you're in. An alternate way would be using the atan2 function.

Answer (score 0):

For imaginary numbers:

1. $z = bi = be^{i\pi/2},\quad b>0$
2. $z = bi = |b|e^{i3\pi/2},\quad b<0$.

Comment: If modulus positive then $e^{\pi/2}$, else $e^{3 {\pi/2}}$

Answer (score 0):

> I know that when converting a complex number of the form $ z = a + bi $, you need to take the $ arctan $ of $\frac{b}{a} $.

I use a different approach to calculate the angle that corresponds to a complex number.  To find the *argument* (i.e. corresponding angle $\theta$) for 
$~(a + bi) = z = re^{i\theta} ~: ~a,b \in \Bbb{R}, ~z \neq 0,$ 
I use the following procedure:

- First, I calculate $~r \in \Bbb{R^+}~$ equal to $\displaystyle ~\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}.$
- Then, I look for the unique angle $(\theta)$, within a modulus of $(2\pi)$, such that $~\displaystyle \cos(\theta) = \frac{a}{r}, ~~\text{and}~~ \sin(\theta) = \frac{b}{r}.$

Answer (score 0):

You can express the polar form of an imaginary number $bi\in\Bbb I$ as:

$$(r,\theta) = \Big(|b|,\, \frac\pi2\cdot\frac b{|b|}\Big)$$

so that the argument is $\pm \pi/2$.  If you prefer angles in non-negative degrees, then.

$$(r,\theta) = \Big(|b|,\, 90^\circ\cdot\Big(2-\frac b{|b|}\Big)\Big)$$

If you are not afraid of the signum function, then

$$(r,\theta) = \big(|b|,\, 90^\circ\cdot(2-\operatorname{sign} b)\big)$$